# How to associate RDP extension to open remote desktop client on 12.04?

Tags: server, remote, rdp, tsclient

The `tsclient` application used to work for opening .rdp files, but Remmina does not seem to work the same way. Does KRDC, Remote Desktop Viewer or some other application work? I'm using Precise Pangolin (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS). I used tsclient successfully on 9.04 (Jaunty Jackalope) by associating `/usr/bin/tsclient`. The problem is intranet-published web pages have the .RDP files, which are needed to download and launch the terminal server client or remote desktop client automatically. The `tsclient` had the features and functionality needed, but `tsclient` is no longer in the repository and is difficult to get all of the dependencies met.

I got these compiling errors for `tsclient-2.0.1` with the latest `libnotify` and `libnm_glib` packages installed:

```
No package 'libnotify' found
No package 'libnm_glib' found
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Install Ubuntu Tweak tool

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa 
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
   ```

   and go to file type manager and add `rdp`.
2. I suggest you will use `remmina` as `.rdp`'s default application

   But this solution may not fit your question, because `.rdp` files taken from Windows are different than what `remmina` uses. So it may be irrelevant to associate `remmina` with `.rdp`.

   So you may rename files saved by `remmina` to `.rdp` so that you can benefit from associating `remmina` with `.rdp` files.
3. Another solution may force `tsclient` to work on ubuntu 12.04:

   Download the `tsclient` package and the relevant dependencies from [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com).

   For a typical 64-bit architecture, the following command would install `tsclient` for you:

   ```
   sudo dpkg --force-all -i tsclient_0.150-4ubuntu2_amd64.deb
   ```

   For 32-bit system:

   ```
   sudo dpkg --force-all -i tsclient_0.150-4ubuntu2_i386.deb`
   ```

Comment: remmina only works with very simple RDP connections and doesn't read all variables in the RDP file saved from Windows.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the approach presented in [kamil's excellent answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/194097/22949) is to overcome the build errors compiling `tsclient`.

In Ubuntu 12.04, no packages called `libnotify` and `libnm_glib` are provided, so it's quite unlikely you have packages by those names installed. I presume you instead have `libnotify4` and `libnm-glib4` installed.

Those packages provide the library binaries for installed programs to use, but they do not provide the [header files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header_file) necessary to build programs from source code that use the libraries. Header files are provided by packages whose names end in `-dev`. **In particular, the packages you need to build programs that use those two libraries are called `libnotify-dev` and `libnm-glib-dev`.** Note that while the binary package have major version numbers in their names (`4` at the end), these `-dev` packages do not.

That should enable you to build `tsclient` from source if you wish to do so, or at least should overcome those *particular* errors in the build process.